# nosuchwindowexception Selenium with PhantomJS Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, phantomjs

I am using headless PhantomJS browser to automate the application using phantomjs driver with selenium. (selenium java version 3.5.2 and phantomjs.exe)

I have a scenario where i will fill the form and submit it and then the browser gets closed and after closing the browser I am reusing the driver reference to get the URL. It works well when I am using the firefox driver with selenium 2.47.0.

Now I switched to the selenium phontamjsdriver and phantombrowser. Here when I make a call to the driver.get(url);after the browser gets closed it is throwing the nosuchwindowexception saying window is closed or inactive. But, the same code is working with the firefox driver

example:

```
driver.get(url);// first time works  
submitForm(driver);//browser window gets closed.  
driver.get(url);
```

The last line is throwing exception as:

```
nosuchwindowexception(selenium java with 3.5.2 version and phantomjs.exe).
```

But works well with the firefoxbrowser with selenium 2.4.7.

Comment: How are you closing the browser , `driver.quit()` or `driver.close()` and are you also using the headless FF ?

Comment: i am not closing the browser with phantom driver.  its the behavir of the application once the form is submitted the broswer window gets closed automatically. It gets closed programatically in the code

Comment: AFAIU , you open one page in your application then click somewhere and a new windows opens up with form , then you fill the form and it gets closed by itself , then you use driver.get('some url') to navigate to some URL, right ?

Comment: i open one page in application then click link. it opens the form on the same window and then i fill the form and it gets closed by itseft. then i use the driver.get("url") to open the browser with same driver instance. then it throws nosuch window exception. but the same code works well with firefox browser. looks like behaviour of phantom browser and firefox is not same

Comment: Are you using explicit wait ? Could you share your code too ? I need to see the code , before I can make any conclusion.

Comment: `myPage.getSubmit().click();
  this.clickMsgBoxYes(driver,"You are about to submit this form, are you sure you wish to continue?");
  this.clickMsgBoxOK(driver,"This form has been successfully submitted.");
driver.get(MYREQUESTS_URL); `

Comment: so when code executes driver.get(MYREQUESTS_URL); it is throwing exception

Comment: Did you try thread.sleep(2000) just before `driver.get(MYREQUESTS_URL);` ? If it works with thread.sleep(2000) , then we can easily replace thread.sleep() to explicit wait.

Comment: It did not work it still throws same exception
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: {"errorMessage":"Currently Window handle/name is invalid

Comment: Yeah sure ....!

Comment: Hey sorry
it got disconnected
are you there in chat room @cruisepandey

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as you migrated from **Selenium v2.47.0** to **Selenium v3.5.2** it's worth to mention a lot have been changed with the availability of **Selenium 3.x**. Now **Selenium-WebDriver** is a **W3C Recommendation Candidate** and is compliant with [**WebDriver W3C Editor's Draft**](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/)

---

### NoSuchWindowException

[**`NoSuchWindowException`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/NoSuchWindowException.html) class extends [**`NotFoundException`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/NotFoundException.html) and is majorly thrown while attempting:

```
WebDriver.switchTo().window(String windowName);
```

Now, a bit more details about your *usecase*, relevant *HTML* and your *code block* would have given us some more ideas what is going wrong. Perhaps the defination of **`submitForm(driver)`** holds the key to the solution of your question.

---

### Best Practices

Here some of the *best practices* you can follow to avoid **`NoSuchWindowException`**:

- Always strore the *Parent Window Handle* in a variable so that you can traverse back to the *Parent Window* as generally required.
- Before invoking **`driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);`** always induce *WebDriverwait* in-conjunction with *ExpectedConditions* method [**`numberOfWindowsToBe(int)`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#numberOfWindowsToBe-int-).
- Once you invoke **`driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);`** induce *WebDriverWait* in-conjunction with *ExpectedConditions* method [**`titleContains(java.lang.String title)`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#titleContains-java.lang.String-) to wait for the *Page Loading* to get completed to continue your *Test Steps* on the newly opened window.
- To switch back to the parent window use the previously stored *windowhandle*.
- Here is a sample code block to demonstrate *Window/Tab* handling:

  ```
  package demo;

  import java.util.Set;

  import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

  public class WINDOW_HANDLE_ITERATE_Firefox 
  {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
      {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
          WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();
          driver.get("http://www.google.com");
          String parent_window = driver.getWindowHandle();
          System.out.println("Parent Window Handle is: "+driver.getWindowHandle());
          System.out.println("Page Title is: "+driver.getTitle());
          ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open('http://facebook.com/');");
          new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));
          Set<String> allWindows_1 = driver.getWindowHandles();
          System.out.println("Total Windows: "+allWindows_1.size());
          for(String hand1:allWindows_1)
          if(!parent_window.equals(hand1))
          {
              driver.switchTo().window(hand1);
              new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("Facebook"));
              String first_child_window = driver.getWindowHandle();
              System.out.println("First Child Window Handle is: "+first_child_window);
              System.out.println("First Child Window Page Title is: "+driver.getTitle());
              driver.close();
          }
          driver.switchTo().window(parent_window);
          System.out.println("Current Window Handle is : "+driver.getWindowHandle()+ " which is same as "+parent_window +", which is the parent window handle" );
          driver.quit();
      }
  }
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  1531917836983   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.20.1
  1531917836993   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:9993
  1531917837915   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\ATECHM~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.W5WqVulBNm9x"
  1531917842220   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 35364
  1531917843126   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
  Jul 18, 2018 6:14:03 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
  INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
  Parent Window Handle is: 4294967297
  Page Title is: Google
  Total Windows: 2
  First Child Window Handle is: 4294967301
  First Child Window Page Title is: Facebook – log in or sign up
  Current Window Handle is : 4294967297 which is same as 4294967297, which is the parent window handle
  ```

Comment: here in my scenario. i am not navigating into new window or opening link in new window. I have only one window which gets closed by the application once it is submitted and its application behavior. i am not closing the window explicitly.So after window gets closed i am unable to reuse the same driver instance to open the window and it is throwing exception. but with firefox its working fine. if i create new phantomdriver instance and make a  call driver.get(url). it is redirecting to login  page which creates new session.

Comment: @RamRamesh Can you update the main question with your code block which `with firefox its working fine`?

Comment: myPage.getSubmit().click(); 
 this.clickMsgBoxOK(driver,"This form has been successfully submitted.");-------once this code get executed the window gets after validfating the data on the alertbox. Now i am trying to get the url of the with the same driverinstance. usually it should be able to recreate the browser window instance and get the url which i am requesting.driver.get(MYREQUESTS_URL); when i call last line of code its throwing exception. basically i have only one window and get closed and trying to recreate the window instance with the same driver instance i have.

Comment: its the same code working for firefox. driver.get(url);// first time works  
submitForm(driver);//browser window gets closed.  
driver.get(url); // throws exception

Comment: to be precise....  public void testSubmit (WebDriver driver) throws Exception {      
  MyPage myPage = (myPage) PageFactory.createPage(MyPage.class, driver);
  MyPage.switchToMe();
  MyPage.getSubmit().click();
  MyPage.getSubmit().click();
  this.clickMsgBoxYes(driver,"You are about to submit this form, are you sure you wish to continue?");
  this.clickMsgBoxOK(driver,"This form has been successfully submitted.");driver.get(MYREQUESTS_URL);
 }

Comment: Actually there are so many wrapper functions like `switchToMe()`, `getSubmit()`, `clickMsgBoxYes()`, `clickMsgBoxOK()` etc for which we don't have a visibility whats happening inside. hence debugging have become difficult. Can you update the question with more details?

Comment: below are the steps i am trying to create testcase. 1. Loginto my application. 2. select a formby url or clicking the link. 3. it opens the page in same window. now that i have only one window.4. fill the form and submit it. now the browser window gets closed 5. now using same driver i am trying to open a new url in my application to test few things related to the submitted form and validate the data. i am using selenium java with 3.5.2 version and phantomjs.exe.panthom driver and panthom headless browser

Answer (score 0):

This may be an issue to bring to the PhantomJS team here https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues

Unfortunately screenshots in Selenium only capture the DOM and not address bar. If you're able to save the pagesource, you may be able to extract the URL. When viewing page source of this page I see  tags which list various 3rd party apps, inside there is a content source which lists the URL.

```
<meta name="twitter:app:url:googleplay" content="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51255939/nosuchwindowexception-selenium-with-phantomjs-java">
```

This may not be true for every site, but could be somewhere to look. You could also try and add this tag in yourself if you're the site owner.